# Query regarding implementing vis.js in Neovis.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, vis.js, vis.js-network

I am implementing Neo4j application in my angular2+ and NodeJS app. Neo4j application provides Neovis.js which is an integration of vis.js . The Code for Neovis.js is as follows -

https://rawgit.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js/master/dist/neovis.js

Using the above Neovis.js code, my nodes look like this -

[image: Nodal Graph Image]

Now i want to beautify these nodes by adding images instead of circular structures, reduce the font-size of relationships (.i.e. - DEPARTMENT, API),etc. So i asked them is there a way out to improve visualization, so they said in the Neovis.js code , we have visjs. Its as follows -

code -

```
  visjs: {
    interaction: {
        hover: true,
        hoverConnectedEdges: true,
        selectConnectedEdges: false,

        multiselect: 'alwaysOn',
        zoomView: false,
        experimental: { }
    },
    physics: {
        barnesHut: {
            damping: 0.1
        }
    },
    nodes: {
        mass: 4,
        shape: 'neo',
        labelHighlightBold: false,
        widthConstraint: {
            maximum: 40
        },
        heightConstraint: {
            maximum: 40
        }
    },
    edges: {
        hoverWidth: 0,
        selectionWidth: 0,
        smooth: {
            type: 'continuous',
            roundness: 0.15
        },
        font: {
            size: 9,
            strokeWidth: 0,
            align: 'top'
        },
        color: {
            inherit: false
        },
        arrows: {
            to: {
                enabled: true,
                type: 'arrow',
                scaleFactor: 0.5
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here in visjs, they asked me to implement the changes i want. But here i reduced the font-size and added many features but nothing changed . And i even want to implement Images for the nodes. How to do that ? And is there a way to integrate vis.js ? Please help.

P.S :

We run the below code to integrate Neovis.js for displaying front-end-

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js/blob/master/examples/simple-example.html

Comment: Have you found a solution how to change neovis.js styling and physics?